# Laravel Call to undefined function yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

Tags: oracle, laravel, nginx, pdo

I am using nginx with php7-fpm with OCI8 enabled, i test the Oracle connection and it is connecting with a plain PHP script.

After PHP artisan serve the error message is : Fatal error: Call to undefined function yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

I already comment config/app.php yajra line.
Also run `php artisan cache:clear`, `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update` 
uncomment and run all commands again

How can i fix this error? Call to undefined function yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

Comment: If you do `echo phpinfo()` on both environments is there any differences relating to the `OCI` modules. Perhaps not enabled on your local php, but is enabled on the php7-fpm php. Do a `which php` and `php --version` to see what your system is actually using. A little googling finds [this](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/54) is that at all related?

Comment: Solved yajra must be called as Yajra with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

I ran throw this issue this week and in my case I had added `extension=oci8.so` to the */etc/php/(version)/apache/php.ini* and also to the */etc/php/(version)/cli/php.ini*. I commented these two and leave only the one in */etc/php/(version)/fpm/php.ini* (I was running laravel with php8.1-fpm), after that `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`.